# Extracting params in traefik.frontend.auth.forward.address service

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

## Summary

I'm trying to set up an authentication passthrough using Traefik's `traefik.frontend.auth.forward.address` setting. My main web service has the `traefik.frontend.auth.forward.address=login.mydomain.com` label on the container. Traefik seems to correctly forward incoming requests intended for `mydomain.com` to `login.mydomain.com`, but when the login form is submitted, the POST request gets turned into a GET request before it hits the login service, and the parameters of the original POST request seem to be missing. The user can never log in.

## Containers

```
docker run -d \
    -l "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:login.mydomain.com; Method:GET, POST" \
    -l "traefik.enable=true" \
    login-service

docker run -d \
    -l "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com" \
    -l "traefik.frontend.auth.forward.address=https://login.mydomain.com" \
    -l "traefik.frontend.auth.forward.authResponseHeaders=cookie" \
    -l "traefik.enable=true" \
    web-service
```

## Question

Using `auth.forward.address`, should I see the parameters from the original POST request in my login service? Since Traefik turns it into a GET request, where in that request should I be looking for the parameters? Or, perhaps I have misconfigured something? Missing a `authResponseHeaders` flag maybe?

## What Works

Requests to `mydomain.com` show the login form from `login-service`, with the URL continuing to show `mydomain.com`; the redirect to `login.mydomain.com` is happening behind the scenes, which is correct.

I have also tested the login service by itself, and it seems to work. It hosts a form that submits a POST request to the service, before responding with 200 OK and a `Set-Cookie` header. In fact, when I go to `login.mydomain.com` directly, I can login, which sets my cookie, and I can go to `mydomain.com` and skip the login screen.

## What Doesn't Work

When submitting the login form, the POST request hits the `login-service` (as evidenced by the logs in that service) as a GET request and the data in the POST request appears to be gone. Traefik adds an `x-forwarded-method` set to `POST`, but I can't find the data in the original POST request. I need the params from my login form to validate them, and they don't appear to be getting through to the login service.

## Traefik Configuration

I don't think anything about my Traefik configuration is relevant here, but I'm including it for completeness.

```
checkNewVersion = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]
sendAnonymousUsage = true

[api]
dashboard = true
debug = true

[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "admin@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tracked down [Traefik's auth forward code](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/middlewares/auth/forward.go). Sure enough, the request body is not passed downstream to the authentication service; only the headers make it that far. So much for default form submit behavior.

To get around this, I reworked my client-side authentication logic to submit a POST request with the credentials *in the header* instead of the body, set using `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader`.

There's one more catch needed to make it work. I need to set cookies client-side using the `Set-Cookie` header returned from the authentication server, but if the server returns a `200 OK` when the login is successful, Traefik will immediately pass along the original request to the user's intended destination -- meaning the `Set-Cookie` header will never make it to the user. What I did to get around this was return a `418 I'm a teapot` when the authentication was successful. This allows the `Set-Cookie` header to make it back to the user's browser so the user's auth token can be set. The client then automatically reloads the intended page, this time with the correct cookie set, and now the auth server returns a `200 OK` if it sees a valid cookie for the requested service.

Here's what the client side code looks like:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    // Override the default form submit behavior.
    // Traefik doesn't pass along body as part of proxying to the auth server,
    // so the credentials have to be put in the headers instead.
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        const data = new FormData(form);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "/", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Auth-Form", new URLSearchParams(data).toString());
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.onload = function(e) {
            if (request.status == 418) {
                window.location = window.location.href;
            } else {
                alert("Login failed.");
            }
        };
        request.send(data);
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>
```

I'm leaving this issue open at least until the bounty runs out because I can't imagine that this is the intended way to do this. I'm hoping someone can weigh in on how `traefik.frontend.auth.forward.address` is supposed to be used. Or, if someone has used another authentication proxy strategy with Traefik, I'm eager to hear about it.

Comment: I think the intent is to authenticate ongoing sessions instead of generating tokens and such for new sessions (it doesn't even return the body in case of a 200, iirc). And most ongoing sessions include a JWT or something similar in the header. They probably designed the feature with that in mind.